# combining jQuery objects

Tags: jquery, html

I have an image and I have a link. How can I use jQuery to make a linked image like this:
`<a href="src"><img src="src"></a>`

```
var image = $('<img>').attr('src', src);
var link = $('<a>').attr('href', src);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method.

```
link.append(image);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function () {
  var src = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a';
  var href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';
  
  var img = $('<img/>').attr('src', src);
  var link = $('<a/>').attr('href', href);
  
  // just set the content of the link to the image
  link.html(img);
  
  $('body').append(link);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i like this solution